# it's well past time

Tags: meaning

Source: [Assembly Language Step by Step—Programming with Linux, 3rd Edition by Jeff Duntemann (2009)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470497025,miniSiteCd-BSG.html)

Example:

> Everything up to this point has been necessary groundwork. I’ve explained
>   conceptually what computers do and have given you the tools to understand
>   the slightly alien numbers that they use; but I’ve said nothing so far about
>   what computers actually are, and **it’s well past time**. We will return to
>   hexadecimal numbers repeatedly in this book; I’ve said nothing thus far about
>   hex multiplication or bit-banging.

What exactly do you think that means? We should have discussed what computers are long before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

In other words, "it is now past the time when we should have started talking about what computers actually are".

The word "well" is used just for emphasis.